# StackOverflow vs. Programmers migration - incorrect? And what can be done about borderline questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migration, software-engineering-se, migration-rejection

With regard to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/146198/why-when-would-it-be-appropriate-to-override-tostring/.

This question started off on StackOverflow, where I believe it belongs and was then migrated to Programmers.

This migration seems wrong to me, but raises another issue about the approach of migration. I have enough rep in StackOverflow to migrate questions. However if a question was to be migrated to Programmers incorrectly, I am powerless to bring it back (I guess because I do not have enough rep on Programmers). This seems like an anomoly.

So I have a few questions:

1. Does the question belong on SO or Programmers (I think SO - it may be a "why" question, but is very much about the implementation details in a specific language, C#)?
2. As an SO user with a reasonably high rep, I have the power to migrate a question away from SO, but not to pull it back, or otherwise veto the move. Should there be such a mechanism (in fact, is there one I don't know about)?
3. Is there a better way of dealing with borderline questions - especially where two sites (StackOverflow and Programmers) have a big potential for overlap? I think in some cases the distinction becomes very subjective.

Comment: I don't think it matters where it lives given it's already been thoroughly answered as long as it's still findable from StackOverflow. Seems odd to do it immediately after it was a featured question on the SO email, though.

Comment: I disagree with that question belonging on SO. It seems like a question about "data structure concepts", "design patterns" and "software architecture".

Comment: given that votes list of this question includes two respectable Pprogrammers users along with Programmers moderator who is also one of the best [experts in site topicality](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/47/chrisf "ChrisF - profile at Programmers"), I would bet 9:1 that migration was done right

Comment: Okay, I reread the question and I have to say that the question and the title do not match very well. The title belongs on Programmers, the body belongs on SO. The question needs to cleaned up.

Comment: @Kobobby - the reason for overriding this method is entirely an technical detail about how ToString is used in the framework (as the default way of displaying the contents of a class) and how the debugger displays classes. There really is no higher concept to it, it isn't "best practice" in a design sense, just in a day to day debugging and usage sense.

Comment: @gnat - interestingly enough, ChrisF has mentioned in the comments of the question that he is not now so sure. There is a real subjective grey area here IMHO.

Comment: @gnat - Rob's right and I think Kobobby has hit the nail on the head. The discrepancy between the title and the body is the source of the confusion. However, the OP will have to clarify which is the true meaning.

Comment: @Rup - I had no idea it was featured in the SO e-mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reversed the migration, with BoltClock's help from SO's side.

I think the question was suitable for both sites, and as such it's reasonable to stay at the site where it was originally asked.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, it looks like a Stack Overflow question to me. He's asking a specific question about the C# language, and it even includes code.

I'll admit to not really understanding the Programmers guidelines all that well, but [if it fits on SO, it should stay there](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).

Comment: +1, bring it back to SO.

Comment: `I'll admit to not really understanding the Programmers guidelines all that well` Don't worry, _no one_ does...

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast: That's not true! I had a friend which had a cousine who knew someone whose grandfather *did* understand them!

Comment: @Kobobby that grandfather probably was at Programmers in good old days, prior to  [Joel's blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/ "Merging Season") mentioning _"Programmers... appears to be degrading into fairly stupid water-cooler nonsense..."_

Comment: @gnat: Didn't Jeff or Joel mention at one point that that post was outdated, and Programmers did outgrow that to the better?

Comment: @Kobobby Our early troubles are over and Programmers is doing great now, my earlier comment was just Friday trolling, The Establishment knows I'm a moderator on Programmers and was just fooling around.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast: Yes, I'm aware of that (well, not exactly that you're Diamond over there, but that you were joking). ;)

Comment: @Kobobby good question. As far as I can tell, this is a **[long and fairly complicated story](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3415/31260 "Jun 2010 to Apr 2011 step by step breakup made by Mark Trapp, with concrete dates, lots of references to Area51, NPR Beta, SE blog, Programmers community, meta posts and other stuff like that...")**

Comment: @gnat Oh come on, if you are going to link to that, at least [link to my answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3413/25936), it's clearly the most helpful... ;P

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast yeah *"What was it --I paused to think --what was it that so unnerved me in the contemplation of the House of NPR?"* Mark's story pales in comparison, no doubt

Comment: @gnat I thought that was going to be a link to [this question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/renaming-the-site-to-match-its-faq-or-changing-the-faq-to-match-the-site-name) or maybe [this one](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3301/changing-the-faq-to-reflect-the-sites-name).

Comment: @TheEstablishment the questions you refer to are too recent to be read by [Kobobby's friend's cousine's knowing someone's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130506/stackoverflow-vs-programmers-migration-incorrect-and-what-can-be-done-about/130508#comment358424_130508) grandfather

Answer (score 2):

This question is definitely on topic for Stack Overflow. We'll gladly have it back, thanks.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Meta Stack Overflow! This answer is a duplicate of [one that had previously been posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130508/153008). Because this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, it's customary to simply upvote an answer if you agree with it. There's no reason to post a duplicate of your own that says the same thing.